# Can I get variable into dynamic sidebar?

Tags: widgets, sidebar, variables

How can I get a variable into a sidebar?

```
$sidebarnum = 4;

dynamic_sidebar('Footer Widget $sidebarnum'); ?>`
```

Comment: Any feedback on this post. Did the answer below solve your issue. If yes, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it. If it did not, feel free to post your own answer and accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
dynamic_sidebar('Footer Widget $sidebarnum');
```

with this

```
dynamic_sidebar('Footer Widget ' . $sidebarnum);
```